# UrlLinker not matching % in url

Tags: javascript, php, regex, url

I am using UrlLinker https://bitbucket.org/kwi/urllinker/src to match URLs in comments on my site

It has worked fine for me since I first used it, however it did not work for this link

```
http://example.com/files/213913702712nqh%297cwGb$_1D_e.jpg
```

This link was matched until the `%` sign and the rest was left as plaintext:

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/213913702712nqh">http://example.com/files/213913702712nqh</a>%297cwGb$_1D_e.jpg
```

How can I modify the REGEX to match the `%` sign? Because that URL is valid.

This is the REGEX

```
{\b(https?://|ftp://)?(?:([^]\\\x00-\x20\"(),:-<>[\x7f-\xff]{1,64})(:[^]\\\x00-\x20\"(),:-<>[\x7f-\xff]{1,64})?@)?((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,62}|(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.|0\.){3}(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0))((:[0-9]{1,5})?(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?)(?=[)'?.!,;:]*([^-_$+.!*'(),;/?:@=&a-zA-Z0-9]|$))}{\b(https?://|ftp://)?(?:([^]\\\x00-\x20\"(),:-<>[\x7f-\xff]{1,64})(:[^]\\\x00-\x20\"(),:-<>[\x7f-\xff]{1,64})?@)?((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,62}|(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.|0\.){3}(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0))((:[0-9]{1,5})?(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?)(?=[)'?.!,;:]*([^-_$+.!*'(),;/?:@=&a-zA-Z0-9]|$))}
```

Comment: By skimming quickly over the source it looks like `$rexPath = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';` does not allow for the "%" character which would explain why it's only matching up to that character in your url. I would simply add it anywhere between the "[]". In fact, I would allow it for `$rexQuery` and `$rexFragment` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must add it to the character class of `$rexpath`:

```
$rexPath      = '(/[!$-/0-9:;%=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the percent sign into the `$rexNonUrl` variable